# Using Histogram as input in R

Tags: r, input, histogram

This is admittedly a very simple question that I just can't find an answer to.

In R, I have a file that has 2 columns: 1 of categorical data names, and the second a count column (count for each of the categories). **With a small dataset, I would use 'reshape' and the function 'untable' to make 1 column and do analysis that way.** The question is, how to handle this with a **large data set**?

In this case, my data is humungous and that just isn't going to work.

My question is, how do I tell R to use something like the following as distribution data:

```
Cat Count
A   5
B   7
C   1
```

That is, I give it a histogram as an input and have R figure out that it means there are 5 of A, 7 of B and 1 of C when calculating other information about the data.

The desired *input* rather than output would be for R to understand that the data would be the same as follows,

A
A
A
A
A
B
B
B
B
B
B
B
C

In reasonable size data, I can do this on my own, but what do you do when the data is very large?

**Edit**

The total sum of all the counts is 262,916,849.

In terms of what it would be used for:

This is new data, trying to understand the correlation between this new data and other pieces of data. Need to work on linear regressions and mixed models.

Comment: what does this ("Means that I'm giving it a histogram and it should this as the data together?") mean? I don't understand. Can you give edit the question and show the desired output for this small example?

Comment: I was in the middle of editing when it was moved. There is no desired output, it is actual a desired input.

Comment: What do you want to do with the data?

Comment: How big is "humungous?"  Are we talking a 100,000 row histogram, or a 1e+9 row histogram?  Are we talking a total for the "Count" column of 1e+9 or 1e+12?  Note that the maximum length vector R can store is a bit over 2 billion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I *think* what you're asking is to reshape a data frame of categories and counts into a single vector of observations, where categories are repeated. Here's one way:

```
dat <- data.frame(Cat=LETTERS[1:3],Count=c(5,7,1))
#  Cat Count
#1   A     5
#2   B     7
#3   C     1
rep.int(dat$Cat,times=dat$Count)
# [1] A A A A A B B B B B B B C
#Levels: A B C
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Would this be suitable for larger data sets?

Comment: How many rows would the histogram have? What is the number of total observations?

Comment: @Lillian Milagros Carrasquillo I'd say yes, this operation is suitable for "larger" datasets, though it of course depends how large they are.  I posted a followup answer demonstrating this.

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the original poster's question because it just reshapes the data.frame by expanding out all of the inputs in a way that would be unfeasible for large data sets.  The more efficient answer is to directly create a histogram object from the pre-binned data, rather than expanding the pre-binned data, and re-binning it.  The `PreBinnedHistogram` function from the [HistogramTools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HistogramTools) package on CRAN would be better.

Answer (score 4):

To follow up on @Blue Magister's excellent answer, here's a 100,000 row histogram with a total count of 551,245,193:

```
set.seed(42)
Cat <- sapply(rep(10, 100000), function(x) {
  paste(sample(LETTERS, x, replace=TRUE), collapse='')
  })
dat <- data.frame(Cat, Count=sample(1000:10000, length(Cat), replace=TRUE))
> head(dat)
         Cat Count
1 XYHVQNTDRS  5154
2 LSYGMYZDMO  4724
3 XDZYCNKXLV  8691
4 TVKRAVAFXP  2429
5 JLAZLYXQZQ  5704
6 IJKUBTREGN  4635
```

This is a pretty big dataset by my standards, and the operation Blue Magister describes is very quick:

```
> system.time(x <- rep(dat$Cat,times=dat$Count))
   user  system elapsed 
   4.48    1.95    6.42
```

It uses about 6GB of RAM to complete the operation.

Comment: Oh thank Nightingale it's fast. I've been racking my brain for how you'd do it using `stats::reshape` or `reshape2`. It doesn't seem straightforward.

Comment: @Zach Just updated some info in the question. Giving your suggestion a shot now!

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on what statistics you are trying to calculate.  The `xtabs` function will create tables for you where you can specify the counts.  The `Hmisc` package has functions like `wtd.mean` that will take a vector of weights for computing a mean (and related functions for standard deviation, quantiles, etc.).  The `biglm` package could be used to expand parts of the dataset at a time and analyze.  There are probably other packages as well that would handle the frequency data, but which is best depends on what question(s) you are trying to answer.

Comment: Yes `wtd.mean` from MHmisc and such are useful functions that don't depend on expanding out the full data set.  Or `PreBinnedHistogram` from HistogramTools if histograms are desired for plotting or other data analysis.

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers are all expanding the pre-binned dataset into a full distribution and then using R's histogram function which is memory inefficient and will not scale for very large datasets like the original poster asked about.  The [HistogramTools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HistogramTools/index.html) CRAN package includes a
`PreBinnedHistogram` function which takes arguments for breaks and counts to create a Histogram object in R without massively expanding the dataset.

For Example, if the data set has 3 buckets with 5, 7, and 1 elements, all of the other solutions posted here so far expand that into a list of 13 elements first and then create the histogram.  `PreBinnedHistogram` in contrast creates the histogram directly from the 3 element input list without creating a much larger intermediate vector in memory.

```
big.histogram <- PreBinnedHistogram(my.data$breaks, my.data$counts)
```